# Python Tkinter Layout management

Tags: python, layout, tkinter

I have attached two pictures down below showing the layout that I am currently getting and the layout which I want in the top frame of the GUI, **ignore** the midframe and bottomframe. In order to keep the code as short as possible I haven't included the rest of the code inside.
[image: Current Layout][image: Layout that I want]

Picture on Left= Layout I am getting. Picture on right = Layout I need

```
from Tkinter import *

root= Tk()
topFrame = Frame(root,bg="grey")
topFrame.pack()
midFrame = Frame(root,bg="lightblue",borderwidth=2,relief=GROOVE)
midFrame.pack()
bottomFrame= Frame(root,bg="lightgreen")
bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

label1 = Label(topFrame, text="Upload Acitivity File:")
label1.pack(padx=5, pady=10)
first_button=Button(topFrame,text="Button 1")
first_button.pack()



label2 = Label(topFrame, text="Select the Activity")
label2.pack(padx=5,pady=10,side=LEFT)

b1 = Radiobutton(topFrame, text="Walking",value=1)
b1.pack(padx=5, pady=10,side=LEFT)
b2 = Radiobutton(topFrame, text="Running",value=2)
b2.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aligning widgets in tkinter can be made much easier by dividing the GUI into meaningful sections and creating a frame for each. You can repeat this operation [multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16317165/4084269) until the alignment is straightforward in each subframe.

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

# Create two frames on top of each other (bg color can help debugging)
frame1 = tk.Frame(root, bg="yellow")
frame2 = tk.Frame(root, bg="blue")
frame1.pack(side=tk.TOP)
frame2.pack(side=tk.TOP)

# Place label1 and button1 side-by-side in frame1
label1 = tk.Label(frame1, text="Upload Activity File:")
label1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
button1 = tk.Button(frame1,text="Button 1")
button1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

# Place label2, b1 and b2 side-by-side in frame2
label2 = tk.Label(frame2, text="Select the Activity")
label2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
b1 = tk.Radiobutton(frame2, text="Walking", value=1)
b1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
b2 = tk.Radiobutton(frame2, text="Running", value=2)
b2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: Screenshot]